# Omnifaces - FullAjaxExceptionHandler - f:ajax onevent status is success

Tags: jsf-2, omnifaces

I'm using Omnifaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler - which is working great, but when I do an ajax call and have an onevent function that is checking for status == 'success' it is still being called, even though the FullAjaxExceptionHandler has rendered an error page. (I'm using JSF(Mojarra 2.1.3 on glassfish 3.1.1)

JSF Code:

`<h:commandButton value="myButton">
    <f:ajax listener="#{myBean.myBeanFunction()}"
            render="someDiv"
            onevent="myFunction"/>
</h:commandButton>`

Javascript Code:

`function myFunction(e)
            {
                if (e.status == 'success') {
                    alert("Success");
                }
            }`

So I need some way of not executing the javascript function if the FullAjaxExceptionHandler is taking me to an error page.

Comment: It's by design not possible to change the ajax response status, a status of error would result in the response data being ignored (and thus the enduser won't get any feedback). What exactly is the functional requirement for which you need a hook on "success" status and how exactly does it fail this way? It can maybe be solved differently.

Comment: I need to display a dialog when the ajax call completes successfully, however when there is an error during the call, it renders the error page, but still tries to show the dialog. The dialog doesn't actually display, but the dialog is modal, so the error page ends up with a modal background, and you can't click anything on the page. Is there any way to not execute the onevent javascript if the FullAjaxExceptionHandler is rendering an error page? Or is there a way to place some sort of data in the onevent javascript function that could be checked so that I don't try to show the dialog?

Comment: I just discovered that it works correctly if you use primefaces p:commandButton, or if you use p:ajax. Not sure why it works differently when using f:ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check as follows if the returned XML response does not indicate that a `render="@all"` has been performed (which would indicate that the entire document will be replaced):

```
if (e.responseXML.getElementById('javax.faces.ViewRoot') == null) {
    // ...
}
```

That it works with `oncomplete` of a PrimeFaces command component is because it does not use the standard JSF ajax API for this and does things thus differently -more intuitively.